# IL, emit default constructor call

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, il

I'm generating new type at runtime, 
After I've generated default constructor I want to generate another one, with parameters.I'm doing it this way :

```
cb = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
                    CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { typeof(bool) });
GenConstructorWithParameters(cb, fields, genFields);
```

The problem is, that I am unable to call default constructor from method GenConstructorWithParameters, because CLR does not allow me to write something like this :

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);        
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, cb.DeclaringType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));//Not allowed to call .GetConstructor() on not created type!
```

How do I emit call to default constructor? Is it possible at all?

tb - instance of `TypeBuilder`, cb - `ConstructorBuilder`

Comment: Oops, not a duplicate, sorry  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `DeclaringType.GetConstructor`, you should pass your current `ConstructorBuilder` for the default constructor.

Basically, whilst building up a type, in places where you might use reflection based methods on existing types, you should instead pass in the builders that you're already working with.

---

So it would be:

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, defaultCB);
```

where `defaultCB` was the `ConstructorBuilder` you declared when defining the default constructor.

Comment: @taras.roshko - I trusted Marc's answer, but I've now reverted to `Call` instead, having just thrown some code together and examined it in Reflector.

Comment: What in heaven's name is "gen"?

Comment: @BrunoSantos - it's whatever the OP already has in their question. However, from context, a *fairly* good guess would be that it's an instance of the [`ILGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) class, since that's the one that has lots of `Emit` methods defined upon it.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`newobj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj.aspx):

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, cb.DeclaringType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
```

Comment: Same NotSupportedException("The invoked member is not supported before the type is created.")

Comment: @taras - then keep hold of the ConstructorBuilder you invented earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objCtor As ConstructorInfo = objType.GetConstructor(New Type() {})

      Dim pointCtor As ConstructorBuilder = pointTypeBld.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, ctorParams)
      Dim ctorIL As ILGenerator = pointCtor.GetILGenerator()

      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, objCtor)

      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, xField)

      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, yField)

      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3)
      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, zField)

      ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

Dim myDynamicType As Type = Nothing
Dim myDTctor As ConstructorInfo = myDynamicType.GetConstructor(aPtypes)
      Console.WriteLine("Constructor: {0};", myDTctor.ToString())
```